# Can you trigger a data-toggle in Bootstrap3 when focus happens?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with this html which works for a mouse click in the input field, properly displaying the datetimepicker "menu".

However I want to trigger the dropdown-menu when the input control gets focus via tab or programmatic focusing.  How do you trigger the toggle with Bootstrap3?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle my-toggle-select" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text"  toggle-on-focus class="input-large" data-ng-model="data.date"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date"
                    data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '.my-toggle-select' }"></datetimepicker>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT ======================

This isn't working:

```
.directive('toggleOnFocus', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            var dataToggle = _element.closest(".dropdown-toggle").parent();
            $log.debug("linking to ", _element);
            _element.on('focus', function(evt) {
                $log.debug("Event ", evt);
                $log.debug("On element ", _element);
                $log.debug("With toggle", dataToggle);
                dataToggle.dropdown();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Produces console output like this:

[image: Console output]

So you can see the focus happen multiple times, the event is logged, but the dropdown never displays.

The control I'm using can be found here: 
https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake, failure to call `dropdown()` with an argument of `'toggle'`, and an extra `.parent()` in the code above.

```
.directive('toggleOnFocus', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            var dataToggle = _element.closest(".dropdown-toggle");
             _element.on('focus', function(evt) {
                 dataToggle.dropdown('toggle');
             });
        }
    };
});
```

Oh the wasted time on things that are just a little bit off!